# Loading a Service before other Services

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, boot, windows-task-scheduler

I have a network critical Windows 7 service. It must start before any network related service on the system, or that network service may fail. My service requires that Winsock is fully initialized by the time it runs.

How can I coerce Windows to load my service at the appropriate time? i.e. Immediately after Winsock is available.

Comment: I know you can configure [delay-loading](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=193888) for services, but I'm not sure if there's a way to force yours to the top of the list. I kind of doubt it. Check into modifying the service's `LoadOrderGroup`. You can do this using `sc.exe` from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `LoadOrder` utility by MS Sysinternals. Found out the group should be "**NetworkProvider**". Also, since the loader loads in lexicographical alphabetical order, I named my process prefixing "Z" so it will load last in the "NetworkProvider" `LoadOrderGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your service depend on other services using the [depends](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) option. To make other services dependent on your service, you'd need to set *their* dependencies.